# Trouble with Login with PayPal redirect_uri mismatch

Tags: paypal, openid-connect

I am trying to configure my NetIQ SocialAccess appliance to allow authentication via Login with PayPal using OpenIDConnect but cannot seem to get my Return URL correct.  I have seen a recent blog entry stating that the matching would become more strict and wonder if anyone can tell me if the difference in these two strings would cause the redirect_uri mismatch error.  SocialAccess is adding a header with a redirect_uri string beginning with **https%3A** rather than **https:** as configured for my application's Return URL.

Answer (score 0):

"%3A" is encoded format of character ":", meaning SocialAccess is adding an encoded url string as your redirect_url, and eventually leading to a mismatch from what you have set in your  APP config.

> URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.
>
> Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be > converted into a valid ASCII format.
>
> URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.